# How to apply condition for all children in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: `Case` and `Artifact`. One `Case` can have zero or many `Artifacts`.

`Case` has `CaseId` as the Primary column.

`Artifact` has `ArtifactId, CaseId, IsEnabled` as columns.

How can I write one condition for all the children for one `Case`? . What I want to do is to show `Cases` whose all `Artifacts` are of a certain status (*enabled*).

Comment: Give us some sample data (As CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements), and what you want the results to be based on that sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from cases c
where not exists (select 1
                  from artifact a
                  where a.caseid = c.caseid and a.isEnabled = 0
                 );
```

Comment: So, for this situations we are forced to use `anti-joins` ? I mean, we should inverse all the conditions.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut . . . There are other ways of expressing this that doesn't reverse the condition.  I think this is the simplest method.